# How to create a line plot by using specific rows from a .xls file with R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, line-plot

I want to create a line plot with two specific rows and first row as the x-axis from a .xls file.

Until now, I tried ggplot which I could not find what should I pass to places which marked with the question marks.

```
dataset <- read_excel("inflation.xls")
p1 <- ggplot() + geom_line(aes(y = ?, x = ?), data = dataset)
```

Here is the expected result and sample of my data.

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99KoI.jpg)

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/US7QT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably try to convert your data into a [tidy format](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) (each row is an observation and columns are variables) before plotting.

In this case,

```
library(dplyr)
target <- c("Turkey", "Germany")
dataset <- gather(dataset, key = "Year", value = "Inflation", -1) %>% # -1 here to gather all columns except the first 
           filter(`Country Name` %in% target) #filter the relevant countries
```

Your dataset should then have a Year column with each year, and an Inflation column with the inflation values.

```
  Country Name  Year Inflation
1  Turkey      1960         1
2 Germany      1960         2
3  Turkey      1961         2
4 Germany      1961         3
5  Turkey      1962         3
6 Germany      1962         4
```

From here it should be clear that Year is the x value and Inflation is the Y value, you want to group by Country so that each country gets its own line.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = dataset, aes(x = Year, y = Inflation, color = Country, group = Country))
```